# Can I hook a c wire adapter to this configuration of a Weil McLain CGa-4-SPDN boiler?

Tags: thermostat, heating

The control panel has:

- a G hook up (wire to thermostat)
- a R hook up (other thermostat wire)
- a W hook up nothing to it
- a C hook up that has a good number of wires running to it.

Can I add another wire to the C terminal?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]! I did a little reformatting to help make the question more readable. I also posted an actual question in the question body, based on what you asked in the title. Please be sure I got your question correct (people will answer that, and if I got it wrong, you won't get the right answer). If I didn't get it right, _please_ [edit] your question to clarify what you're actually asking. Once you've done that, take a few moments to take the [tour] while you're waiting for an answer - that will help you learn how this site is different than others.

Comment: You can add another wire to the C terminal, but to what end?  If you're hooking up a smart thermostat, search the site for other questions about that because many people have tried.  Boiler thermostats typically switch the control wires differently that a HVAC style unit and are sometimes not compatible without additional work/adapters.

Comment: A clear picture of the wiring diagram from the wall or inside door panel of the boiler would be helpful, and a description of what wires go to the thermostat.  Presumably you need an adapter because there are no spare wires and no C wire and running new cable to the thermostat is difficult?

Comment: Can you post photos of the boiler's nameplate please, as well as if this boiler is feeding a hot water or a steam system? Weil-McLain boilers in particular have a bad habit of wiring their safety controls in odd places, which means that connections that are "obvious" to a scorched-air type run a high risk of bypassing important protections (like low-water cutoffs)